# How to convert this trigger from TSQL to PL/pgSQL

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I have this code in SQL Server and need an equivalent in PostgreSQL.

#### Table and insertion

```
CREATE TABLE  authentification (
    id int primary key,
    utilisateur varchar(15),
    typeCompte varchar(15)
)

CREATE TABLE droit (
    id int primary key ,
    description varchar(15),
)

insert into droit values (1, 'Description...')

CREATE TABLE permission (
    id_authentification int references authentification (id),
    id_droit int references droit (id),
    primary key(id_authentification,id_droit)
)
```

### Trigger

```
 go 
  create trigger affectePermission
  on authentification
  after insert
  as
  begin
   declare @idAuthentification int
   set @idAuthentification = (select id from inserted)
   insert into permission values (@idAuthentification,1)
  end
 go
```

Comment: your trigger ain't great as it is, what happens if there's more than one row in inserted

Comment: You'll need to show the PostgreSQL code you have managed to write so far otherwise how can anyone suggest what might need fixing?

Comment: I believe Postgres has [tag:PLpgSQL], not Oracle [tag:plsql].

Comment: Yes I was talking about PostegreSQL. Thank you, I found the solution in the comment below

Answer (score 2):

Sure, let's dive into the translation of this trigger from TSQL (SQL Server's SQL dialect) to PL/pgSQL (PostgreSQL's SQL dialect). The trigger in question is called affectePermission, and it fires after an insert into the authentification table to insert a corresponding record into the permission table.

Here is how you might define a similar trigger in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION affecte_permission() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO permission (id_authentification, id_droit) 
  VALUES (NEW.id, 1);
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER affecte_permission
AFTER INSERT ON authentification
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE affecte_permission();
```

In the TSQL trigger, you used the inserted special table to get the id of the newly inserted row. In PostgreSQL, you use the NEW special variable instead. The NEW variable contains the new database row for INSERT/UPDATE operations in row-level triggers. Note also that in PostgreSQL, we first declare a function (affecte_permission in this case) that contains the trigger's operations, then we bind this function to a table using the CREATE TRIGGER statement.

However, you should consider that while using triggers might make the database more self-contained and "intelligent", it can sometimes make application logic more difficult to understand or debug, because parts of it are tucked away in the database. If you're using an ORM like Sequelize, TypeORM, or Hibernate, for example, it may be more maintainable to implement this sort of logic at the application layer.

Remember to always carefully weigh the trade-offs of implementing logic in the database versus in your application.

I hope this helps, and happy coding!

Comment: Then can you confirm the answer :) @OmarM'bairik

Comment: Many of your answers appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). As a heads-up, [posting of AI-generated content is not permitted on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). 

If you used an AI tool for assistance on this answer, could I ask you to (1) Reply in a comment here confirming that it was AI-generated, along with what tool (e.g., ChatGPT, Bing Chat, Copilot, etc.) -- We're compiling data on AI-assisted answers and could use your help. (2) After commenting, I recommend deleting your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).